# undefined method `the_microposts_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm following the http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
and I'm in chapter10 --build the microposts
but I named the_microposts not microposts
and then I had this problem:

When I visit static_page/home , it shows:

> undefined method `the_microposts_path' for #<#:0xb628402c>

and the application trace is:

> app/views/shared/_the_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__the_micropost_form_html_erb___1052260201__619399208'
>   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:9:in`_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb_*733532872*_628014758'

It seems that I didn't defined the method?
But I had defined it in my static_pages controller:

```
def home
    @the_micropost = current_user.the_microposts.build if signed_in?
end
```

My home page:

```
<section>
        <%= render 'shared/the_micropost_form' %>
</section>
```

and my _the_micropost_form.html.erb is:

```
<%= form_for(@the_micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

my user models:

```
has_many :the_microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

the_micropost models:

```
belongs_to :user
```

My routes:

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
root  'static_pages#home'
match '/signup',   to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

is anything wrong??
I always follow the steps, is it because I defined the different name?(the_microposts as microposts)

Comment: I am guessing it's supposed to be `micropost_path`, but just to be sure, please post either the result of `rake routes` or your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: Sure, I have edited it~! is it anything wrong?

Comment: You do not have route for your micropost resource.  Add `resources :microposts` after `resources :sessions...`

Comment: Thank!I know how to solve it know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define route for `Micropost` resource just like you have defined for `users` and `sessions`.  Update your `config/routes` to include `resource :microposts`.

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts
root  'static_pages#home'
...
```